# Can't access my laptop's localhost through an Android app

Tags: android, python, django, localhost, django-rest-framework

So I did a research before posting this and the solutions I found didn't work, more precisely:

-Connecting to my laptop's IPv4 `192.168.XXX.XXX` - didn't work

-Conecting to `10.0.2.2` (plus the port) - didn't work

I need to test an API i built using Django Rest framework so I can get the `json` it returns, but i cant access through an Android app i'm building (I'm testing with a real device, not an emulator). Internet permissions are set on Manifest and i can access remote websites normally. Just can't reach my laptop's localhost(they are in the same network)

I'm pretty new to Android and Python and Django as well (used to built Django's Rest Framework API).

EDIT: I use `localhost:8000/snippets.json` or smth like this to connect on my laptop.

PS: I read something about XAMP server... do I need it in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What command are you using to run the server? Are you running it through the built-in web server? Or through a more industrial one like Apache or nginx?

Comment: 10.0.2.2 only works for the emulator. localhost will not work either, since it would refer to the Android device itself. The IP address is your best bet. Is your machine connected to the same wifi network as the device? Do you have a firewall that might be blocking the connection?

Comment: Both on the same connection. I have a MYSQL db running on MYSQL workbench and the Django Rest API connects to that database to get the data
Edit: guess its through the built-in web server..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you started the server like this?

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then, try to connect to 192.168.XXX.XXX:8000

Comment: I just ran the API through PyCharm. and it runs the server automatically, but i'll try your suggestion. BTW What does that 0.0.0.0 mean? Shouldnt be localhost or something?

Comment: It worked fine.. I can access the webservice through my phone's browser

Comment: It means to open up the application to all networks that can reach your computer. Through a LAN, your computer can be reached by its IP.

Comment: Thank you! I searched all over google and couldnt find this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above, but failed to work in my case. Then with running
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 I also had to add my IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py, which solved this issue.

eg.
Add your ip to allowed hosts in settings.py
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.XXX.XXX']

Then run the server
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Answer (score 0):

#### *Others have already given the answer but those solutions didn't work for me when I was running Django server on Ubuntu and was trying to access it from my Mobile app.*

#### Following is what worked for me:

## Step 1: Run server to access it from your IP

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

## Step 2: Open port in firewall (Missing step in above given answers - Needed for Ubuntu)

```
$ sudo ufw enable 
$ sudo ufw allow 8000
```