# Django REST client test with specific IP

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest-django

The [Django REST docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) read the address from `META`.
So I have to create `Whitelist` model storing the ip-address/subnet for it. Not a big deal I had all `302` subnets in my database already.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class BlacklistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for blacklisted IPs.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        blacklisted = Blacklist.objects.filter(ip_addr=ip_addr).exists()
        return not blacklisted
```

**Problem:**
I want to test whitelist from other ip-address rather than `127.0.0.1`
How can I do that in `pytest`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716724/cant-access-my-laptops-localhost-through-an-android-app AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383540/authenticate-by-ip-address-in-django AND http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/

Comment: @AnupYadav Thanks for your attention. None of them related to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @rpkilby
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5775#issuecomment-360734150

Because `APICLient` inherit from the same source. Set the header is very straight forward.

```
client = APIClient(REMOTE_ADDR='x.x.x.x')
```

Answer (score 1):

Write an integration test: using `requests` or an equivalent library to call your API.

If you plan to test it once, just deploy the app in another host and run the test.

If you want automated testing, consider using a CI/CD pipeline. Put your API in a container, put the test code in another container, then trigger these tests when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think I have to go beyond unittest to docker level